# Guardar la salida de un Foreach en un array

Tags: scala

Tengo un fichero de X número de líneas con este formato:

```
1::F::1::10::48067
```

Lo que busco es que lea tantas lóneas como yo le paso a la siguiente función:

```
case class User(userID: String, Gender: String, Occupation: String, Zipcode:
 String)

def getNthLineUser(lines: Array[String]) =  {

  val rddUsersSplit = lines.foreach(e => println(e.split("::")(0), e.split("::")(1), e.split("::")(2), e.split("::")(3)))

}

getNthLineUser(RDDusers.take(2))
```

Lo que quiero hacer con esta función es que lea cada una de las líneas y que haga un split de "1::F::1::10::48067" por "::" y esto guardarlo en una secuencia de [User] para después convertirlo a DF con la función `.toDF`.

No veo la manera de convertir la salida que es [Unit] a Sequence o Lista. Lo que he conseguido hacer es simplemente leer cada linea y separarlo por "::" e imprimirlo por pantalla.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso de `foreach` únicamente busca algún efecto colateral, no la transformación de un flujo de datos. En *Programación Funcional* debería evitarse siempre. Emplea cualquier otro método funcional, como por ejemplo `map`:

```
val rddUsersSplit = lines.map{ line =>
   val Array(userID, gender, occupation, zipcode, _) = line.split("::")
   User(userID, gender, occupation, zipcode)
}.toDF
```

Comment: Gracias! @ChemaCortes.